# binary search tree indexing

Tags: c, tree

I am having trouble getting the element from the binary tree at a specific index. The function that i am having trouble with is generic tree_get_at_index(tree_node* t, int index) {
The assignment asks me to find the element at a particular index in a binary tree. For example the 0 index should return the lowest element in the binary tree and the index = treesize should return the largest element in the tree. i have a size function in my tree which works correctly but i cannot get the indexing to work for some reason. any help would be appreciated. thank you

Right now i am getting seg fault after the tree runs once.

```
  #include "tree.h"

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
    /* Memory Management */

/* This constructor returns a pointer to a new tree node that contains the
 *  given element.*/
tree_node* new_tree_node(generic e) {
    /*TODO: Complete this function!*/
    tree_node* to_return = malloc(sizeof(tree_node));
    to_return->element = e;
    to_return->left = NULL;
    to_return->right = NULL;
    return to_return;
}

/* This function is expected to free the memory associated with a node and all
 *  of its descendants.*/
void free_tree(tree_node* t) {
    /*TODO: Complete this function!*/
    if (t != NULL){
        free_tree(t->left);
        free_tree(t->right);
        free(t);
    }
}
    /* End Memory Management */




    /* Tree Storage and Access */


bool tree_contains(tree_node* t, generic e) {
    /*TODO: Complete this function!*/
    /*
    if (t == NULL || t->element != e) {
        return false;
    }
    else if (t->element == e) {
        return true;
    }
    return tree_contains(t,e);
}
*/
    if(t == NULL )
        return false;
    else if(t->element == e)
        return true;
    else if (e<t->element)
         return tree_contains(t->left,e);
    else
        return tree_contains(t->right,e);

}


tree_node* tree_add(tree_node* t, generic e) {
    /*TODO: Complete this function!*/

    if(t==NULL)
    t = new_tree_node(e);
    else if(e == t->element)
        return t;
    else if(e > (t->element))
        {
            t->right = tree_add(t->right,e);
        }
    else if(e < (t->element))
        {
            t->left = tree_add(t->left,e);
        }
    return t;
}

tree_node* tree_remove(tree_node* t, generic e) {
    /*TODO: Complete this function!*/
    if (t == NULL) return t;

    else if (e < t->element)
        t->left = tree_remove(t->left, e);
    else if (e > t->element)
        t->right = tree_remove(t->right, e);

    else
    {
        if (t->left == NULL)
        {
            tree_node *temp = t->right;
            free(t);
            return temp;
        }
        else if (t->right == NULL)
        {
            tree_node *temp = t->left;
            free(t);
            return temp;
        }
    else {
            tree_node* current = t->right;
            tree_node* temp = t->right;

        while (current->left != NULL)
            current = current->left;
        t->element = current->element;
        while (temp->left->left != NULL)
            temp = temp->left;
        temp->left = current->right;
        free(current);

    }
    }
    return t;
}
    /* End Tree Storage and Access */




    /* Size and Index */

/* Return the size of the tree rooted at the given node.
 *  The size of a tree is the number of nodes it contains.
 *  This function should work on subtrees, not just the root.
 *  If t is NULL, it is to be treated as an empty tree and you should
 *  return 0.
 *  A single node is a tree of size 1.*/
int tree_size(tree_node* t) {
    /*TODO: Complete this function!*/
    if (t==NULL) 
        return 0;
    else    
        return(tree_size(t->left) + 1 + tree_size(t->right));
}

/* Return the element at the given index in the given tree.
 *  To be clear, imagine the tree is a sorted array, and you are
 *  to return the element at the given index.
 *
 *  Assume indexing is zero based; if index is zero then the minimum
 *  element should be returned, for example. If index is one then
 *  the second smallest element should bereturned, and so on.*/
generic tree_get_at_index(tree_node* t, int index) {
    //assert(index >=0 && index < tree_size(t));
    /*TODO: Complete this function!*/
    //tree_node* new_node = t;
//  int min = 0;
//  int max = tree_size(t);
//  int current = (min+max)/2;
int current = index;
printf("tree size: %d \n", tree_size(t));

    //while( new_node != NULL){
        if(current == (tree_size(t)-1)){
            return t->element;
            printf("index = tree size \n");
        }

        else if(index < (tree_size(t->left))){
            //current--;
        return tree_get_at_index(t->left, index); 
        printf("index < tree size  \n");        //= new_node->right;
        }

        else if(index > (tree_size(t->left))){
        return tree_get_at_index(t->right, index);
        printf("index > tree size  \n");
        }
        return t->element;
    //return (generic)0;

}
    /* End Size and Index */
```

Comment: Please describe your specific problem better than "I can't get it to work for some reason". Please provide a [mcve], test input, expected behaviour and actual behaviour. Review [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more guidance on how to improve your question.

Comment: How was your binary tree build ? it could help a lot with making an answer

Comment: @dvhh i put the entire binary tree here. my problem is with the last function of the code. it doesn't return anything, it just seg faults when i try to run tests on it. i am pretty sure my other functions are working

Comment: what is the complexity constraint for the desired function ? as the code could become quite complex if your tree is unbalanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will try filling a virtual array, as you know the size of each subtree you could skip the indexes

```
generic tree_get_at_index(tree_node* t, int index) {
    // sanity check
    assert(t);
    assert(index > 0);

    int leftCount=tree_size(t->left);
    if(index < leftCount ) {
        // good chance that the node we seek is in the left children
        return tree_get_at_index(t->left, index);
    }
    if(index==leftCount) { 
        // looking at the "middle" of the sub tree
        return t->element;
    }
    // else look at the right sub tree as it was its own array
    return tree_get_at_index(t->right, index - leftCount - 1);
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you soooooooo much!!!!
i was wondering i had to do something like index-leftCount-1 at the end but i left out the 1 so i was getting seg fault.
THANK YOU SIR @dvhh! Really Appreciate it!

Comment: Between just curious how did you know that we had to subtract 1 from index - leftcount?

Comment: on the current node, if you are searching on the right subtree, that mean you are skipping the left subtree nodes count ( `-  leftCount` ) plus the current node you are looking at ( hence the `- 1` ).

Comment: Visualizing your binary tree as a sorted array ( which is the goal of the function ) would help you a lot in understanding, but this implementation a

Comment: But this implementation has a lot of complexity as the call to `size` has a complexity of O(n) and it could be called multiple times and could easily makes the function having a O(n*n) complexity if the tree is badly balanced , I do believe that it would be faster to just flatten the tree until you reach the desired index ( making it  O(n) ).

Comment: Another way to reduce complexity would be to store the size at the node level, as it only need to be updated on insertion/deletion

Comment: yup found that to be very useful by storing the size at node level. makes the algorithm faster!! THANKS :)

Answer (score 0):

```
generic tree_get_at_index(tree_node* t, int index) {
assert(index >=0 && index <= tree_size(t));//I don't know how you define the tree_size function,but,according to the "if" below,you need to add equal mark
printf("tree size: %d \n", tree_size(t));

//while( new_node != NULL){
    if(index == tree_size(t)){
        return t->element;
    }

    else if(index <= tree_size(t->left)){//I think you miss the equal situation here
        //current--;
    return tree_get_at_index(t->left, index);   //= new_node->right;
    }

    else /*if(index > tree_size(t->left))*/{//do not need any condition here
    return tree_get_at_index(t->right, index);
    }
//    return t->element;    //unnecessary
//return (generic)0;

}
```

Comment: thanks
i tried it but it seg faults when i try to enter index